# Ignore touches/gestures in the blank space of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a Map View (Google Maps not MapKit) underneath a `UICollectionsView` and would like to allow the map to be panned/zoomed but since the `UICollectionView` is set to take up the whole screen, it intercepts all touch events leaving the map static.

For some reference, this is what I currently have and the reason I'm setting the `UICollectionView` to be fullscreen is so I can animate the positions of the cells individually within all the screen space.

[image]

I've tried rewriting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36471345/1322878) in Swift but it's throwing a `nil when unwrapping` :

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let indexPath: IndexPath? = self.indexPathForItem(at: point)
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell? = (self.cellForItem(at: indexPath!))
    if (cell != nil) && convert(point, to: cell?.contentView).x >= 0 {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Rather than detecting whether the touch event happened inside a cell, I just checked if the event happened past a certain `y` point and handled it accordingly.

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    if point.y > cardContainerY {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Where `cardContainerY` is a `CGFloat` that's calculated off of the currently focused card (since the cards can be expanded, moved within the `y` space).